# Node Server Not Loading CSS File

Tags: javascript, html, css, server

I'm making a chat application using a node server but when I start the node server and point my browser to localhost:3000 it loads the HTML document but not the CSS file which is supposed to load when the HTML document loads. How do you load the CSS file so that the HTML document uses it?

### HTML document code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO Chat by Flow</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="chat.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<body>
    <table align="center" id="chat-box">
        <td>
            <ul id="messages"></ul>
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Press enter to send a message..." autocomplete="off" id="m">
            </form>
        </td>
    </table>
</body>
```

### JavaScript document code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var port = 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

});

http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined any routes that would provide the CSS file. The only route you've defined is

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});
```

...which will only ever serve `chat.html`.

To serve other files/resources, define other routes, perhaps a catch-all route that serves any matching file from a public directory.

For instance, [this tutorial](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) says you can serve any static files from the directory `public` by doing this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

More about routing in [the routing tutorial](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html). That whole series of tutorials may well be useful, in fact.